# Is it possible to achieve Atomic resolution with the following parameters of a Scanning Probe Microscope?

Tags: microscopy

[image: Problem at hand]

I understand that the formula for Resolution is the Dimension of the image/Dimension of the object, however I am still unable to solve this. Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.